# Django 2 Настройка системы комментариев

Tags: html, css, django

Проблема следующая: когда я добавляю новый комментарий под публикацией на своем сайте, он отображается нормально, но если вдруг зажать какую-либо клавишу или написать очень длинное слово, то текст не переносится, а выходит за пределы полей. Как с этим бороться?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не к Джанго, это обычная html верстка

Comment: Почитайте про word-wrap https://basicweb.ru/css/css_pr_word-wrap.php, если уж на то пошло

Answer (score 1):

Только причём тут `django`?

Добавьте текстовому полю css свойство [`overflow-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap), которое отлично воспринимают все браузеры.

Comment: *не все браузеры

Comment: @Александр ну да, какое-то старьё не поддерживает, поэтому нужно `word-wrap` ещё указывать)